# ASP.NET Custom Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

[An example of what I want. The first column in particular and it's sub rows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9aRV.gif)

I'm looking to make a gridview in ASP.NET using C# that looks similar to the image above.

I'd like the first column to be manually set since those values will never change.

The part that I'm having trouble with is adding rows under the first column that I can label.

To show again this is what I'd like:

```
MyHeader     SecondHeader
SubHeader1   DBData
SubHeader2   DBData
Subheader3   DBData
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting your data? Are you using a DataSet, DataReader, DataTable, or XML?

You will probably need to build the data. You could do that by getting your data and building a DataTable, or XML, or List, etc. The first column you would statically populate then the remaining columns would be dynamically populated from your datasource. Once you have your data shaped they way you want you would bind that to the Grid.

Comment: I'm using a SQL DataSource to pull from a database.
The whole goal is to pull from the database and populate a grid view with the data.

I can build a table but it's horizontal as such:

Comment: Off the top of my head and without seeing code as to what you are doing I would ditch the SqlDataSource and use maybe a DataReader to get your data. Then read through that data to build you a DataTable in the way you want it displayed. Ex: the first column being static, second being data from the DR, etc. Then you can bind that DataTable that has your shaped data to the GridView.